# I am losing one minute every day and my day is 23:59 and not 24

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have my day starting at 00:00 02/Nov/2013 and it ends at 23:59 because the new day is at 00:00 03/Nov/2013 - the math 23:59 - 00:00 I get 23:59 , that means I am losing 1 min every day.
Do I need to add +1 min every time to get 24:00 as result. 
If so how can I handle the problem: 23:59 started and ends 23:59 because of the new day?

Sometime clicking few times in 1 min is giving me

```
Opt1 clock start 12:30 end 12:30 = 0 min
Opt2 clock start 12:30 end 12:30 = 0 min
Opt1 clock start 12:30 end 12:30 = 0 min
Opt2 clock start 12:30 end 12:31 = 1 min
```

So long It is fine but I don't know if "clock start 23:59 end 23:59" is actual work done or it was a mistake.
If it were a mistake then 0 min is just fine, but if it were not a mistake then I lose 1 min.

I work on a small timer and I cannot find the solution of that problem.

Maybe I need extra confirmation from the user?

But it is switching automatically to new day when it reaches 23:59:59 so I get 23:59 as last point for the previous day and the new day starts at 00:00.

How to get the right time? 
The same is for 11:59 pm and 12:00 am  - again the day ends at 11:59 pm because the new starts at 12:00 am, right?

So how to compensate that 1 min?

UPDATE:

the time format is
     SimpleDateFormat foutputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

Parsing to Date and then doing simple math

```
 mint+= (finishd[i].getTime()/60000) - (startd[i].getTime() / 60000);

 ////System.out.println(mint);
 int h=(int)mint/60;
 int m=(int)mint-(h*60);
 ////System.out.println("Min: " +mint);
 String totaltime = h + "h"+":" + m+"min";
 ////System.out.println("H: " + h + "Min: " + m);
```

The problem is when I have: start 01/03/2004 00:00 and end 01/03/2004 23:59 . The next day is starting at 02/03/2004 00:00 .
I get 23h:59min worked time and not 24 - for a whole day I use SQL database to save and read the data. Data format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" ;

Almost there :D
The last problem for me is that I need to do the math like this:

```
pause 10:20 - 10:40 = 20 min OK
working 10:40 - 12:42 = 2h:2min OK
pause 12:42 - 12:57 = 15 min OK
working 12:57 - 12:57 = 0 OK
pause 12:57 - 12:57 = 0 OK
working 12:57 - 16:00 = 3h:3min OK
Total work 5h:5min / pause 35min OK
```

at the end is coming the 23:59 issue:

```
 working 22:00 - 23:59 = 1h:59m missing 24! 1min lost

 NEW DAY working 00:00 - 04:30 = 4h:30min OK
```

So how to fix the last 23:59 as is it can be 
      23:59 - 23:59 pause = 0 min OK

or it can be

```
  day1 23:59 - day2 00:20  = 21min ?
```

but the SQL can store the info only as 00-59min 00-23h

And then if I need the total working and total pause for that day:
I can to sum all records for that day and I will get 23:59h total when I do pause + work

Comment: While this is tagged Java, the syntax really is not. What exactly are we seeing here?

Comment: Put down the glass and go to bed. Tomorrow - when you read this again - your problem will be solved - seemingly magically.

Comment: If you are losing time, you might have a problem with Weeping Angels.  Just don't blink!

Comment: down voting for what??? I thin that you guys are drunk and not me.

Comment: @JohnBG - Don't complain.  "Drunk" is the charitable interpretation :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something wrong with the way you are *thinking* about this problem.

Every day had 60 * 24 minutes = 1440.  The first one is 00:00.  The last one is 23:59.

The reason that `minutes(23:59) - minutes(00:00)` is not 1440 is that that is not the correct way to calculate the number of minutes in a day!  The correct way `minutes(day 2 00:00) - minutes(day 1 00:00)`.

This is primary school level maths.

Comment: He's going to bill you in increments of 23:59 minutes for his work on this problem.. You don't have to pay, just return with a "divide by zero" error :)

Answer (score 1):

This is partly about "inclusive/exclusive" or closed/open bounds, and partly about subtraction.

The day starts at 0000 hours. The same day finishes at 2400 hours -- which is an *endpoint* you can measure to, not a time you can start at.

Thus, a day is correctly 24 hours.

You can "approximate" the endpoint as 23:55, 23:59, 23:59, 23:59:59, 23:59:59.999 or however close you want to *approximately but not correctly* approach it. But the actual correct endpoint will always be 2400 hours aka 0000 hours the next day.

Don't store "end of day" times as 23:59, falsely using an inaccurate approximation instead of getting the fundamentals correct is only going to cause more problems.

When calculating "work duration" times, a simple rule:

1. Round the start time down to the nearest previous minute.
2. Round the end time up to the next minute.

This will ensure logged work-duration is always >= 1 minute, unless both start & end occur pretty much the exact same millisecond. Make sure your code will work with a 0 duration anyway -- it can charge it at 0, that's fine, it just shouldn't crash.

The same issues arise in looping & graphics -- a good loop *starts from* it's lower bound (inclusive) but terminates *below* it's upper bound (exclusive). This gives the property that hi-lo=count.

Similarly for pixels -- where we can best visualize each little pixel as a coloured square *between grid lines*. We measure *grid lines*, and fill pixels *between them*. Thus a rectangle from grid line 0 to grid line 1 fills only one pixel between those bounds, and correctly gives a width of 1.